# What is the origin of "one's eyes are bigger than one's stomach"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of *your eyes are bigger than your stomach*? Does it only refer to taking more food than you can eat?

Online dictionaries such as [Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eyes%20are%20bigger%20than%20one's%20stomach) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_eyes_bigger_than_one%27s_stomach) define the phrase, but don't offer any information about its origin. They also don't say anything about using the phrase in broader applications, similar to how *bite off more than one can chew* is rarely used in a food context.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means; for origins, the metaphor seems fairly straightforward. A dictionary could provide more color.

Comment: In my experience the expression is used in cases where someone initially expected to be able to eat all of the food that they took but then came to realise it was too much after they started eating. (As compared to deliberately taking more than you can eat in one sitting with the intention of saving some for later.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phrase might be older (I know some similar Danish from 14th c), but have it's full form in Montaigne's essay [*Of the Cannibals*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3600/3600-h/3600-h.htm#link2HCH0030) (c. 1580, first translation to English in 1603) and here used metaphorically about other things than food:

> "I am afraid our eyes are bigger than our bellies, and that we have more curiosity than capacity; for we grasp at all, but catch nothing but wind."

The meaning is also evident in Lyly's [*The Anatomy of Wit*](https://archive.org/details/euphuesanatomyof00lylyuoft)  (from the same year 1578/1580, p. 311 in Arbers 1868-edition):

> "But thou art like the Epicure, whose belly is sooner filled than his eye".

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the synonym "belly" is specifically used in this phrase, i.e. "your eyes are bigger than your belly" in other words, something was so delicious you took a large portion, but couldn't eat it all.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bigger+than+your+stomach%2Cbigger+than+your+belly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbigger%20than%20your%20stomach%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbigger%20than%20your%20belly%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As a child I only ever heard "stomach".